# How to set default selection in segmented control in ortuman/SwiftForms

Tags: ios, swift, forms

I took the question from

https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms/issues/147

The included sample form contains a segmented control. I attempt to set the default selected value using "row.value = 1 as AnyObject", though this does not seem to work. How does one set the default selection for the segmented control.

Thanks again for all of your efforts.

(Posted by appsird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is a bug, but I have a workaround for you ;-)

Just use the appearance dictionary to set the index of the segmented control.

(Code from the example of the project)
```java
        row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.segmented, type: .segmentedControl, title: "Priority")
        row.configuration.selection.options = ([0, 1, 2, 3] as [Int]) as [AnyObject]
        row.configuration.selection.optionTitleClosure = { value in
            guard let option = value as? Int else { return "" }
            switch option {
            case 0:
                return "None"
            case 1:
                return "!"
            case 2:
                return "!!"
            case 3:
                return "!!!"
            default:
                return ""
            }
        }

```
    //this alone has just no effect
    row.value=2 as AnyObject?

    row.configuration.cell.appearance = ["titleLabel.font" : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0), "segmentedControl.tintColor" : UIColor.red]

    //you can either set the appearance dictionary as a whole
    row.configuration.cell.appearance = ["titleLabel.font" : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0), "segmentedControl.tintColor" : UIColor.red, "segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex": 2 as AnyObject]

    //or set the value in the dicionary afterwards
    row.configuration.cell.appearance["segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex"]=2 as AnyObject

    //the best way IMHO is to set the index via the value (in that way the row.value is the model for the segmented control, like it should be)
    row.configuration.cell.appearance["segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex"]=row.value

    section4.rows.append(row)
```

```

Running that code the segmented control is pre filled with your set value

[image: bildschirmfoto 2016-12-07 um 09 52 14]

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. The source code compares the values with ===. This means for non-reference types it always false. The following code part does that: (sorry for pasting source code in comment)

var idx = 0
        for optionValue in options {
            if optionValue === value {
                segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = idx
                break
            }
            idx += 1
        }